# configuring username and password in jndi properties for ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, jndi

I have the below spring configuration to connect to ActiveMQ:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"   class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://10.3.2.3:61616" />
    <property name="userName"
        value="Platform.user.consumer" />
    <property name="password" value="Test123"></property>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="7" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to configure the properties in the external property file and want to load using JNDI. I have configured the JNDI parameters inside the properties like below:

```
#Active MQ properties
  java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
  java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
  connectionFactoryNames=connectionFactory
  #register the queue in the JNDI using the below form
  #queue.[queueName]=
  queue.myQueue=com.inputqueue
```

How can I configure the `Platform.user.consumer` and `password` property in the properties file. Please let me know since this is not mentioned in the documentation of Active MQ

Comment: surely the password is configured on the server as part of the JNDI creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jndi InitialContext i think you will loose the power of spring to configure the factory...
But you can load these properties like pwd or user or any property from properties file like this if this what you need

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.17.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Like this you can use ${password} to be replaced with the value "Test123" of the key "password" from springcontext.properties
Eg :
password=Test123